# Android childs Actionbar remains the same as parent when trying to add UP button

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm new in Android development and created my first app consisting of displaying a scrollable list of products as ImageViews and the possibility to access the details of each one by doing a Long Click on it. The app contains three sorts of activities : a splash activity at the start of the app, a main activity that displays a list of products and items activities for each product.

The splash activity doesn't have an action bar, it just has a background image that shows up at the launching of the app for 2 seconds. The main activity contains an ActionBar labelled "Products", while for each product or as I called them "Item", its ActionBar was supposed to be labelled as "Item x". At first it was working like this, but there was no return button, meaning that every time I access an Item after a long click from the main Activity, I can't get back and the app closes.

To solve this issue, I tried to add an UP button in the action bar for each item activity, following android's tutorial on https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action , where I did it this way:

On the AndroidManifest.xml for an item:

```
<activity android:name=".Item7Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
```

On the item activity :

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Item 7");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now I have encountered a new problem, the UP button doesn't appear at all on items ActionBar and the title remains the same as their parent which is the main activity. I don't know where the issue is coming from, the app is working as expected except for the action bar.

Here is some part of my code :

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androtp3">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/tp3_app_logo"
    android:label="Products"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/tp3_app_logo_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Item7Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Item6Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Item5Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Item4Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Item3Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Item2Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Item1Activity" android:parentActivityName="com.example.androtp3.MainActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```

Item1 activity (the code is the same for the others) :

```
public class Item1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item1);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Item 1");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Item layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Item1Activity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/item1_desc"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/item1"></ImageView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/prix"
    android:textColor="#E91E63"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp">

</TextView>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/avecgar"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sansgar"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:textColor="#E91E63"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/item1_desc"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/livraison"
    android:textColor="#E91E63"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/livraison_type1"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/garantie"
    android:textColor="#E91E63"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:text="@string/garantie1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:text="@string/lien"
    android:textColor="#E91E63"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
    android:text="@string/lien1"
    android:textColor="#E91E63"
    />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I think the problem may be in one of the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

for back button :

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Item7");     
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and also need to override some functions :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but that doesn't work, the action bar on the activity remains with the label "Products" (app label) and no return back button.

Comment: Please add you both activity code and layout so i can figure out.. what's going wrong in it

Comment: I updated my post by adding activity's layout, should there be anything else ? by the way item activity's java in the post is the old one, since by adding the instructions you proposed it didn't change